# Layout does not appear in android emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I'm new to Android programming and i'm doing tutorial from layouts from http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html  . Relative layout tutorial exactly. I did everything they say but when I try to start app in android emulator there are no buttons, textfields etc. Only name of app shows at the top. What is wrong? Is this a problem with emulator? I'm using Eclipse Version: 3.7.1.

EDIT:

```
package pchot.tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Tutorial1Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

### }

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="pchot.tutorial"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Tutorial1Activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Layout is copy/paste from http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

EDIT:

Ok, problem solved. I needed to delete "Hello World, Tutorial1Activity!" from string.xml file which was autocreated during creation of project in Eclipse.

Comment: Do you know about the Logcat http://lampcms.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-get-logcat-view-pane-in-eclipse.html and or DDMS http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html? We would need information from that most likely.

Comment: Maybe you can show us your code so we could let you know where you're wrong?

Comment: You're calling `setContentView(...)` I presume?

Comment: It would help us answer if you post it.

Comment: @TryTryAgain: my log from LogCat shows something strange. First of all there is error:  "E/AndroidRuntime(197): ERROR: thread attach failed" but before it, VM seems to be some how killing process of my activity: D/ActivityManager(60): Uninstalling process pchot.tutorial. Sadly right now I'm not familiar with any kind of debuging in Android, I'm just starting.

Comment: hm it is more like a adb config problem. Could you edit your message to put all the Logcat debug?

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified you manifest.xml file? Maybe you haven't modify it to make it aware that the launched main activity is the activity you've just created.

Comment: Activity was created automaticly when I created project in Eclipse and from what I know it is correct

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare anything in your `onCreate()` method.

For `Button` declare `Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit)`

Implement onClickListener if you want the button to listen to clicks.

For `TextView`, declare `TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview)`